# how to fix junit test to return value?

Tags: java, data-structures, junit, null, deque

My data structures project on dequeues is passing all junit tests except for one. the "removeFrontRemoveRear" test. It keeps returning null instead of the 
student name.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Dequeue <E> {
private int front;
private int rear;
private E[] elements;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 5;

/**
 * Constructor sets up an empty double-ended
 * queue
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Dequeue() {
    elements  = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    front = 0;
    rear = elements.length  - 1;    
}

/**
 * Inserts item at the front of the dequeue. Throws 
 * an exception if the item could not be inserted
 * @param anEntry the item to be added (Student)
 * @return true 
 */
public boolean addFront(E anEntry) {
    if (empty()) {
        front = rear = 0;
        elements[front] = anEntry;
    }
    else if (isFull()) {
        reallocate();
        front = (front + (elements.length - 1)) % elements.length;
    }
    else {
        front = (front + (elements.length - 1)) % elements.length;
    }
    elements[front] = anEntry;
    return true;
}

/**
 * private method to check if the dequeue is full
 * @return true only if dequeue is full (has 
 * 1 empty spot) 
 */
private boolean isFull() {
    if (size() == elements.length -1) {
        return true; 
    }
    return false;

}
/**
 *Doubles and adds 1 to the size of the dequeue
 *then reallocates the data.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void reallocate() {
    E[] newData = (E[]) new Object[size() * 2 + 1];
    int indexOfFront = front;
    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        newData[i] = elements[indexOfFront];
        indexOfFront = (indexOfFront + 1) % elements.length;
    }
    rear = size() - 1;
    front = 0;
    elements = newData;
}
/**
 * Inserts item at the rear of the dequeue. 
 * Throws an exception if the item could not be inserted
 * @param anEntry the entry being inserted into the end of the queue
 * @return true
 */
public boolean addRear(E anEntry) {

    if (empty()) {
        front = rear = 0;
        elements[rear] = anEntry;
    }
    else if (isFull()) {
        reallocate();
        rear = (rear + 1) % elements.length;
    }
    else {
        rear = (rear + 1) % elements.length;
    }
    elements[rear] = anEntry;
    return true;
}

/**
 * This method checks if the dequeue is empty
 * @return true if the dequeue is empty. otherwise
 * returns false
 */
public boolean empty() {
        if (front == 0 && rear == elements.length-1) {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

/**
 * @return the dequeue's iterator
 */
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new dequeueIterator();
}

/**
 * implementation of Iterator interface 
 * with inner class
 */
private class dequeueIterator implements Iterator<E> {
    private int index;
    private int count = 0;

    /**
     * references the front dequeue element 
     * and initializes the dequeueIterator object
     */
    public dequeueIterator(){
        index = front;
    }

    /**
     *@return true it there are additional
     * elements in the dequeue
     */     
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return  count < size();
    }

    /**
     * @return the next element in the queue
     */
    @Override
    public E next() {
        if(!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        E returnValue = elements[index];
        index = (index + 1) % elements.length;
        count++;
        return returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * removes the elements accessed by the 
     * iterator object
     */
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

/**
 * //Returns the entry at the front of the 
 * dequeue without removing it; returns
 * NoSuchElementException if the dequeue 
 * is empty
 * @return the object at the front of dequeue
 */
public E peekFront() {
    if (empty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else 
        return elements[front];

}

/**
 * returns the item at the rear of the dequeue, throws
 * NoSuchElementException if empty.
 * @return the element in the rear
 */
public E peekRear() {
    if (empty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else 
        return elements[rear];
}

/**
 *Removes the entry at the front of the dequeue and
 *returns it if the dequeue is not empty. If the 
 *dequeue is empty, throws a NoSuchElementException
 * @return front element before removing it
 */
public E removeFront() {
    if (empty()) 
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
        E temp = elements[front];
        elements[front] = null;
        front = (front++) % elements.length;
        return temp;
}

/**
 * Removes the entry at the rear of the dequeue and
 *returns it if the dequeue is not empty. If the 
 *dequeue is empty, throws a NoSuchElementException
 * @return rear element before removing it
 */
public E removeRear() {
    if (empty()) 
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
        E temp = elements[rear];
        elements[rear] = null;
        rear = (rear + elements.length - 1) % elements.length;
        return temp;
}

/**
 * Gets the amount of elements in the dequeue
 * @return the number of elements in the dequeue
 */
public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    int indexOfFront = front;
    int nextRearPosition = (rear + 1) % elements.length;
    while(indexOfFront != nextRearPosition) {
        count++;
        indexOfFront = (indexOfFront + 1) % elements.length;
    }
    return count;
}
}

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class DequeueTest {
Dequeue<Student> q;
Student s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    q = new Dequeue<Student> ();
    s1 = new Student("John", "Doe");
    s2 = new Student ("Jane", "Smith");
    s3 = new Student ("Bob", "Taylor");
    s4 = new Student ("Anne", "Frank");
    s5 = new Student("Frank", "Gauvin");
    s6 = new Student("Kevin", "Austin");
    s7 = new Student ("Cindy", "Bryant");
    s8 = new Student ("Peter", "Lander");
}

@Test
public void testaddFrontAddRear() {
    q.addFront(s1);
    q.addFront(s2);
    q.addFront(s3);
    assertThat(q.peekFront(), is(s3));     // assertEquals(s3, q.peekFront());
    q.addRear(s4);
    q.addRear(s5);
    q.addFront(s6);
    q.addRear(s7);
    assertThat(q.peekRear(), is(s7));      // assertEquals(s7, q.peekRear());
    assertThat(q.size(), is(7));           // assertEquals(7, q.size());
} 

@Test
public void testRemoveFrontRemoveRear() {
    q.addFront(s1);
    q.addFront(s2);
    q.addFront(s3);
    q.addRear(s4);
    q.addRear(s5);
    q.addFront(s6);
    q.addRear(s7);
    assertThat(q.removeFront(), is(s6));   // assertEquals(s6, q.removeFront());
    assertThat(q.removeRear(), is(s7));    // assertEquals(s7, q.removeRear());
    assertThat(q.removeFront(), is(s3));   // assertEquals(s3, q.removeFront() );
    assertThat(q.size(), is(4));           // assertEquals(4, q.size());
    assertThat(q.removeRear(), is(s5));    // assertEquals(s5, q.removeRear());
    assertThat(q.removeFront(), is(s2));   // assertEquals(s2, q.removeFront());
    assertThat(q.size(), is(2));           // assertEquals(2, q.size());
    assertThat(q.removeFront(), is(s1));   // assertEquals(s1, q.removeFront());
    assertThat(q.removeRear(), is(s4));    // assertEquals(s4, q.removeRear());
    assertTrue(q.empty());
    assertTrue(q.size() == 0);  

} 

@Test
public void testIterator() {
    q.addFront(s1);
    q.addFront(s2);
    q.addFront(s3);
    q.addRear(s4);
    assertEquals(4, q.size() );
    q.addRear(s5);
    q.addFront(s6);
    q.addRear(s7);
    assertEquals(7, q.size() );
    Iterator <Student> iter = q.iterator();
    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        list.add(iter.next() );
    }
    assertThat(list.get(0), is(s6));       // assertEquals(s6, list.get(0));
    assertThat(list.get(1), is(s3));       // assertEquals(s3, list.get(1));
    assertThat(list.get(2), is(s2));       // assertEquals(s2, list.get(2));
    assertThat(list.get(3), is(s1));       // assertEquals(s1, list.get(3));
    assertThat(list.get(4), is(s4));       // assertEquals(s4, list.get(4));
    assertThat(list.get(5), is(s5));       // assertEquals(s5, list.get(5));
    assertThat(list.get(6), is(s7));       // assertEquals(s7, list.get(6));
} 

@Test
public void testPeekFrontOnEmptyQueue() throws NoSuchElementException  {
    assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () ->
      {Dequeue<Student> q = new Dequeue<Student>();
       q.peekFront();});
}

@Test
public void testRearFrontOnEmptyQueue() throws NoSuchElementException{
    assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () ->
      {Dequeue<Student> q = new Dequeue<Student>();
       q.peekRear();});
}

@Test
public void testRemoveFrontOnEmptyQueue() throws NoSuchElementException {
    assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () ->
      {Dequeue<Student> q = new Dequeue<Student>();
       q.removeFront();});
}

@Test
public void testRemoveRearOnEmptyQueue() throws NoSuchElementException
{ 
    assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () ->
      {Dequeue<Student> q = new Dequeue<Student>();
       q.removeRear();});
}
}

/** Abstraction of a Student entity */

public class Student implements Comparable <Student> {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

/** Initialize a Student
  @param first firstName
  @param last lastName
*/
public Student(String first, String last) {
  firstName = first;
  lastName = last;
}

/** Mutator Method
  @param aName firstName
*/
public void setFirstName(String aName) {
  firstName = aName;
}

/** Accessor Method
  @return firstName of this Student
*/
public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
}

/** Mutator Method
  @param aName lastName
*/
public void setLastName(String aName) {
  lastName = aName;
}

/** Accessor Method
  @return lastName of this Student
*/
public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  String str = "";
  str += (lastName + "," + firstName);
  return str;
  }

 /* this version overloads the equals method (note the
 signature of this method).
*/
 public boolean equals(Student s) {
  return ( (this.lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(s.lastName)) &&
           (this.firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(s.firstName)));

 }

 /* We need to override this method so indexOf and
 contains methods work.  Both of them use this version
 equals method
 */
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (obj == null) return false;
     if (obj == this) return true;
     if (!(obj instanceof Student)) return false;
     else {
         Student s = (Student) obj;
         return ( this.equals(s));  // calls the 
equals(Student) method
     }
}

/**
@return
a negative integer if "s1 < s2"; 0 if "s1 == s2"
a positive integer if "s1 > s2"
*/
@Override
public int compareTo(Student s) {
  int result = lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.lastName);
  if (result != 0) return result;
  else
      return (firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.firstName));
}
}
```

The expected result is  but the actual result was null.
I am not sure what to try. I am drawing a blank. The error is brought forth in line 55 of dequeueTest.

Comment: Your `empty()` method looks suspect.  Shouldn’t it be `return front == rear;`?

Comment: @VGR if front == rear the double ended queue has 1 element in it that is both the front and rear. If the dequeue is empty rear is 1 position behind front